# MapHttpRoute going to wrong controller method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Hi I have 2 GET methods on with no arguments and one with a string argument, when I add a string to the Query args, I'd like it to go to the second GET, but its going to the first.

(am new to C# so plz be gentle!)

**Controller:**

```
// GET api/clientwithclocksites
        public IEnumerable<ClientWithWorkSites> Get()
        {
            return this.clientRepository.GetClientsWithClockSites();
        }

        // GET api/clientwithclocksites/TEST
        public ClientWithWorkSites Get(String clientCode)
        {
            return this.clientRepository.GetClientsWithClockSites(clientCode);
        }
```

**WebAPIConfig.cs:**

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**Attempting URL:**

```
http://localhost:35790/api/clientwithclocksites/TEST
```

**Desired method:**

```
public ClientWithWorkSites Get(String clientCode)
```

**Actual Method:**

```
public IEnumerable<ClientWithWorkSites> Get()
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself.Just needed to change the route parameter argument variable name from `id` to match the method argument name `clientCode`

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{clientCode}",
                defaults: new { clientCode = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```